# Android: Arabic font

Tags: android, fonts, arabic

I am trying to parse an XML file which contains complex arabic letters ..

When i tested on android 2.3.7, not all arabic letters are supported, there is still some complex ones appear as squares ..

But when tested on android 4.0.4, all letters appear great ..

I needed to find the .ttf arabic font used in 4.0.4 or the best android arabic font to force it in my application to work fine on all versions, can you help me please?

I tried DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf and DroidSansArabic.ttf but not the same like android 4.0.4 ..

Thanks ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this solution:

get the roboto font as used on android 4 , from [here](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html). if that doesn't work , you can try out other fonts , such as the [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download) font . other fonts are available [here](http://openfontlibrary.org/en/search?license=Apache%202.0) for example .

then , put the file into your assets folder , and for each of the views that need to show text (like textView) , use the font :

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(face);
```

i've tried hebrew in the past and it showed fine . sadly , the special dots (called "NIKUD") didn't show so well so you might have similar problems for arabic .

Comment: Manyy thanks .. Roboto was exactly what i needed, working great .. other links are useful too.

Comment: does it look ok for arabic ? it didn't look so well for hebrew when using NIKUD .

Comment: yes it look good for the characters i need, and gives same result as android 4.. hope newer fonts in android to support everything ..

Comment: i doubt it . sadly hebrew is not so commonly used so they don't put much effort for making it better. the weird thing is that google has announced that RTL support got better , but they didn't explain what has changed and what can be used . not only that , but i remember that in their presentation they showed the arabic and hebrew text , but it was aligned to the left ...

Answer (score 2):

This is a library code I use in my Goyalla dictionary  to reshape Arabic on Android version before 4.0. You can get an example for it from github [example](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper).

At the same time you need to invoke the *.ttf file.

```
package go.goyalla.dict.arabicDictionary.file;

public class ArabicReshape {

    static final char RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR = 0x0001;
    static final char RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_ALEF = 0x0006;
    static final char RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR = 0x0004;
    static final char RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR_LAM = 0x0003;
    static final char TANWEEN = 0x000C;
    static final char TASHKEEL = 0x000A;
    static final char TATWEEL_CHAR = 0x0008;
    static final char NORIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR = 0x0007;
    static final char NOTUSED_CHAR = 0x000F;
    static final char NOTARABIC_CHAR = 0x0000;

    static final char RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR_MASK = 0x0880;
    static final char RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK = 0x0800;
    static final char LEFT_CHAR_MASK = 0x0080;

    private static final char allchar[][] = {
            { 0x0621, 0x0007, 0xFE80, 0xFE80, 0xFE80, 0xFE80 },
            { 0x0622, 0x0806, 0xFE81, 0xFE82, 0xFEF5, 0xFEF6 },
            { 0x0623, 0x0806, 0xFE83, 0xFE84, 0xFEF7, 0xFEF8 },
            { 0x0624, 0x0804, 0xFE85, 0xFE86, 0xFE86, 0xFE86 },
            { 0x0625, 0x0806, 0xFE87, 0xFE88, 0xFEF9, 0xFEFA },
            { 0x0626, 0x0881, 0xFE89, 0xFE8A, 0xFE8B, 0xFE8C },
            { 0x0627, 0x0806, 0xFE8D, 0xFE8E, 0xFEFB, 0xFEFC },
            { 0x0628, 0x0881, 0xFE8F, 0xFE90, 0xFE91, 0xFE92 },
            { 0x0629, 0x0804, 0xFE93, 0xFE94, 0xFE94, 0xFE94 },
            { 0x062A, 0x0881, 0xFE95, 0xFE96, 0xFE97, 0xFE98 },
            { 0x062B, 0x0881, 0xFE99, 0xFE9A, 0xFE9B, 0xFE9C },
            { 0x062C, 0x0881, 0xFE9D, 0xFE9E, 0xFE9F, 0xFEA0 },
            { 0x062D, 0x0881, 0xFEA1, 0xFEA2, 0xFEA3, 0xFEA4 },
            { 0x062E, 0x0881, 0xFEA5, 0xFEA6, 0xFEA7, 0xFEA8 },
            { 0x062F, 0x0804, 0xFEA9, 0xFEAA, 0xFEAA, 0xFEAA },
            { 0x0630, 0x0804, 0xFEAB, 0xFEAC, 0xFEAC, 0xFEAC },
            { 0x0631, 0x0804, 0xFEAD, 0xFEAE, 0xFEAE, 0xFEAE },
            { 0x0632, 0x0804, 0xFEAF, 0xFEB0, 0xFEB0, 0xFEB0 },
            { 0x0633, 0x0881, 0xFEB1, 0xFEB2, 0xFEB3, 0xFEB4 },
            { 0x0634, 0x0881, 0xFEB5, 0xFEB6, 0xFEB7, 0xFEB8 },
            { 0x0635, 0x0881, 0xFEB9, 0xFEBA, 0xFEBB, 0xFEBC },
            { 0x0636, 0x0881, 0xFEBD, 0xFEBE, 0xFEBF, 0xFEC0 },
            { 0x0637, 0x0881, 0xFEC1, 0xFEC2, 0xFEC3, 0xFEC4 },
            { 0x0638, 0x0881, 0xFEC5, 0xFEC6, 0xFEC7, 0xFEC8 },
            { 0x0639, 0x0881, 0xFEC9, 0xFECA, 0xFECB, 0xFECC },
            { 0x063A, 0x0881, 0xFECD, 0xFECE, 0xFECF, 0xFED0 },
            { 0x063B, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x063C, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x063D, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x063E, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x063F, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x0640, 0x0888, 0x0640, 0x0640, 0x0640, 0x0640 },
            { 0x0641, 0x0881, 0xFED1, 0xFED2, 0xFED3, 0xFED4 },
            { 0x0642, 0x0881, 0xFED5, 0xFED6, 0xFED7, 0xFED8 },
            { 0x0643, 0x0881, 0xFED9, 0xFEDA, 0xFEDB, 0xFEDC },
            { 0x0644, 0x0883, 0xFEDD, 0xFEDE, 0xFEDF, 0xFEE0 },
            { 0x0645, 0x0881, 0xFEE1, 0xFEE2, 0xFEE3, 0xFEE4 },
            { 0x0646, 0x0881, 0xFEE5, 0xFEE6, 0xFEE7, 0xFEE8 },
            { 0x0647, 0x0881, 0xFEE9, 0xFEEA, 0xFEEB, 0xFEEC },
            { 0x0648, 0x0804, 0xFEED, 0xFEEE, 0xFEEE, 0xFEEE },
            { 0x0649, 0x0804, 0xFEEF, 0xFEF0, 0xFEF0, 0xFEF0 },
            { 0x064A, 0x0881, 0xFEF1, 0xFEF2, 0xFEF3, 0xFEF4 },
            { 0x064B, 0x000C, 0x064B, 0xFE70, 0xFE71, 0xFE70 },
            { 0x064C, 0x000C, 0x064C, 0xFE72, 0xFE72, 0xFE72 },
            { 0x064D, 0x000C, 0x064D, 0xFE74, 0xFE74, 0xFE74 },
            { 0x064E, 0x000A, 0x064E, 0xFE76, 0xFE77, 0xFE76 },
            { 0x064F, 0x000A, 0x064F, 0xFE78, 0xFE79, 0xFE78 },
            { 0x0650, 0x000A, 0x0650, 0xFE7A, 0xFE7B, 0xFE7A },
            { 0x0651, 0x000A, 0x0651, 0xFE7C, 0xFE7D, 0xFE7C },
            { 0x0652, 0x000A, 0x0652, 0xFE7E, 0xFE7F, 0xFE7E },

            { 0x0653, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0654, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0655, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0656, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0657, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0658, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0659, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x065A, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x065B, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x065C, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x065D, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x065E, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x065F, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x0660, 0x000B, 0x0660, 0x0660, 0x0660, 0x0660 },
            { 0x0661, 0x000B, 0x0661, 0x0661, 0x0661, 0x0661 },
            { 0x0662, 0x000B, 0x0662, 0x0662, 0x0662, 0x0662 },
            { 0x0663, 0x000B, 0x0663, 0x0663, 0x0663, 0x0663 },
            { 0x0664, 0x000B, 0x0665, 0x0664, 0x0664, 0x0664 },
            { 0x0665, 0x000B, 0x0665, 0x0665, 0x0665, 0x0665 },
            { 0x0666, 0x000B, 0x0666, 0x0666, 0x0666, 0x0666 },
            { 0x0667, 0x000B, 0x0667, 0x0667, 0x0667, 0x0667 },
            { 0x0668, 0x000B, 0x0668, 0x0668, 0x0668, 0x0668 },
            { 0x0669, 0x000B, 0x0669, 0x0669, 0x0669, 0x0669 },

            { 0x066A, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x066B, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x066C, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x066D, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x066E, 0x000E, 0x065E, 0x065E, 0x065E, 0x065E },
            { 0x066F, 0x000E, 0x065F, 0x065F, 0x065F, 0x065F },

            { 0x0670, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x0671, 0x0804, 0xFB50, 0xFB51, 0xFB51, 0xFB51 },
            { 0x0672, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0673, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0674, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0675, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0676, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0677, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0678, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x0679, 0x0881, 0xFB66, 0xFB67, 0xFB68, 0xFB69 },
            { 0x067A, 0x0881, 0xFB5E, 0xFB5F, 0xFB60, 0xFB61 },
            { 0x067B, 0x0881, 0xFB52, 0xFB53, 0xFB54, 0xFB55 },
            { 0x067C, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x067D, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x067E, 0x0881, 0xFB56, 0xFB57, 0xFB58, 0xFB59 },
            { 0x067F, 0x0881, 0xFB62, 0xFB63, 0xFB64, 0xFB65 },
            { 0x0680, 0x0881, 0xFB5A, 0xFB5B, 0xFB5C, 0xFB5D },

            { 0x0681, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0682, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0683, 0x0881, 0xFB76, 0xFB77, 0xFB78, 0xFB79 },
            { 0x0684, 0x0881, 0xFB72, 0xFB73, 0xFB74, 0xFB75 },
            { 0x0685, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x0686, 0x0881, 0xFB7A, 0xFB7B, 0xFB7C, 0xFB7D },
            { 0x0687, 0x0881, 0xFB7E, 0xFB7F, 0xFB80, 0xFB81 },
            { 0x0688, 0x0804, 0xFB88, 0xFB89, 0xFB89, 0xFB89 },
            { 0x0689, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x068A, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x068B, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x068C, 0x0804, 0xFB84, 0xFB85, 0xFB85, 0xFB85 },
            { 0x068D, 0x0804, 0xFB82, 0xFB83, 0xFB83, 0xFB83 },
            { 0x068E, 0x0804, 0xFB86, 0xFB87, 0xFB83, 0xFB83 },
            { 0x068F, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0690, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x0691, 0x0804, 0xFB8C, 0xFB8D, 0xFB8D, 0xFB8D },
            { 0x0692, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0693, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0694, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0695, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0696, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x0697, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x0698, 0x0804, 0xFB8A, 0xFB8B, 0xFB8B, 0xFB8B },
            { 0x0699, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x069A, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x069B, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x069C, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x069D, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x069E, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x069F, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06A0, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06A1, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06A2, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06A3, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06A4, 0x0881, 0xFB6A, 0xFB6B, 0xFB6C, 0xFB6D },
            { 0x06A5, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06A6, 0x0881, 0xFB6E, 0xFB6F, 0xFB70, 0xFB71 },
            { 0x06A7, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06A8, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x06A9, 0x0881, 0xFB8E, 0xFB8F, 0xFB90, 0xFB91 },
            { 0x06AA, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06AB, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06AC, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06AD, 0x0881, 0xFBD3, 0xFBD4, 0xFBD5, 0xFBD6 },
            { 0x06AE, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x06AF, 0x0881, 0xFB92, 0xFB93, 0xFB94, 0xFB95 },
            { 0x06B0, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06B1, 0x0881, 0xFB9A, 0xFB9B, 0xFB9C, 0xFB9D },
            { 0x06B2, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },

            { 0x06B3, 0x0881, 0xFB96, 0xFB97, 0xFB98, 0xFB99 },
            { 0x06B4, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06B5, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06B6, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06B7, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06B8, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06B9, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06BA, 0x0804, 0xFB9E, 0xFB9F, 0xFB9F, 0xFB9F },
            { 0x06BB, 0x0881, 0xFBA0, 0xFBA1, 0xFBA2, 0xFBA3 },
            { 0x06BC, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06BD, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06BE, 0x0881, 0xFBAA, 0xFBAB, 0xFBAC, 0xFBAD },
            { 0x06BF, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06C0, 0x0804, 0xFBA4, 0xFBA5, 0xFBA5, 0xFBA5 },
            { 0x06C1, 0x0881, 0xFBA6, 0xFBA7, 0xFBA8, 0xFBA9 },
            { 0x06C2, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06C3, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06C4, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06C5, 0x0804, 0xFBE0, 0xFBE1, 0xFBE1, 0xFBE1 },
            { 0x06C6, 0x0804, 0xFBD9, 0xFBDA, 0xFBDA, 0xFBDA },
            { 0x06C7, 0x0804, 0xFBD7, 0xFBD8, 0xFBD8, 0xFBD8 },
            { 0x06C8, 0x0804, 0xFBDB, 0xFBDC, 0xFBDC, 0xFBDC },
            { 0x06C9, 0x0804, 0xFBE2, 0xFBE3, 0xFBE3, 0xFBE3 },
            { 0x06CA, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06CB, 0x0804, 0xFBDE, 0xFBDF, 0xFBDF, 0xFBDF },
            { 0x06CC, 0x0881, 0xFBFC, 0xFBFD, 0xFBFE, 0xFBFF },
            { 0x06CD, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06CE, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06CF, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06D0, 0x0881, 0xFBE4, 0xFBE5, 0xFBE6, 0xFBE7 },
            { 0x06D1, 0x000F, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 },
            { 0x06D2, 0x0804, 0xFBAE, 0xFBAF, 0xFBAF, 0xFBAF },
            { 0x06D3, 0x0804, 0xFBB0, 0xFBB1, 0xFBB1, 0xFBB1 } };

    public static String reshape(String Str) {
        String Temp = " " + Str + " ";
        char pre, at, post;
        StringBuilder reshapedString = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        int len = Str.length();

        char post_post;
        char pre_pre = ' ';

        while (i < len) {
            pre = Temp.charAt(i);
            at = Temp.charAt(i + 1);
            post = Temp.charAt(i + 2);

            int which_case = getCase(at);
            int what_case_post = getCase(post);
            int what_case_pre = getCase(pre);
            int what_case_post_post;
            int what_case_pre_pre;
            // which_case=0x000F&
            // Log.v("what case"," :" +which_case);
            int pre_step = 0;
            if (what_case_pre == TASHKEEL) {
                pre = pre_pre;
                what_case_pre = getCase(pre);
            }
            if ((what_case_pre & LEFT_CHAR_MASK) == LEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                pre_step = 1;

            }

            switch (which_case & 0x000F) {

            case NOTUSED_CHAR:
            case NOTARABIC_CHAR:

                reshapedString.append(at);

                i++;
                continue;
            case NORIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR:
            case TATWEEL_CHAR:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));

                i++;
                continue;
            case RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR_LAM:

                if ((what_case_post & 0x000F) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_ALEF) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(post, pre_step + 2));
                    i = i + 2;

                    continue;
                } else if ((what_case_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;

                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TANWEEN) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TASHKEEL) {
                    post_post = Temp.charAt(i + 3);
                    what_case_post_post = getCase(post_post);
                    if ((what_case_post_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;

                        continue;

                    } else {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;

                    }

                } else {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                }

            case RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR:
                if ((what_case_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TANWEEN) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TASHKEEL) {
                    post_post = Temp.charAt(i + 3);
                    what_case_post_post = getCase(post_post);
                    if ((what_case_post_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;

                    } else {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;

                    }

                } else {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                }
            case RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_ALEF:
            case RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                i = i + 1;
                continue;
            case TASHKEEL:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;
                pre_pre = pre;
                continue;
            case TANWEEN:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;
                pre_pre = pre;
                continue;

            default:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;

            }

        }

        return reshapedString.toString();
    }

    public static String reshape_reverse(String Str) {
        String Temp = " " + Str + "   ";
        char pre, at, post;
        StringBuilder reshapedString = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        int len = Str.length();

        char post_post;
        char pre_pre = ' ';

        while (i < len) {
            pre = Temp.charAt(i + 2);
            at = Temp.charAt(i + 1);
            post = Temp.charAt(i);

            int which_case = getCase(at);
            int what_case_post = getCase(post);
            int what_case_pre = getCase(pre);
            int what_case_post_post;
            int what_case_pre_pre;
            // which_case=0x000F&
            // Log.v("what case"," :" +which_case);
            int pre_step = 0;
            if (what_case_pre == TASHKEEL) {
                pre = Temp.charAt(i + 3);
                what_case_pre = getCase(pre);
            }
            if ((what_case_pre & LEFT_CHAR_MASK) == LEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                pre_step = 1;

            }

            // System.out.println("##letter "+ pre);
            switch (which_case & 0x000F) {

            case NOTUSED_CHAR:
            case NOTARABIC_CHAR:

                reshapedString.append(at);

                i++;
                continue;
            case NORIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR:
            case TATWEEL_CHAR:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));

                i++;
                continue;
            case RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_ALEF:

                // System.out.println("--letter "+ pre);

                if ((what_case_pre & 0x000F) == RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR_LAM) {
                    pre = Temp.charAt(i + 3);
                    // System.out.println("++letter "+ pre);
                    what_case_pre = getCase(pre);
                    pre_step = 0;
                    if ((what_case_pre & LEFT_CHAR_MASK) == LEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                        pre_step = 1;

                    }
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step + 2));
                    i = i + 2;

                    continue;
                } /*
                 * else if
                 * ((what_case_post&RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK)==RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK
                 * ){ reshapedString.append(getShape(at,2+pre_step)); i=i+1;
                 * 
                 * continue;
                 * 
                 * 
                 * } else if (what_case_post==TANWEEN){
                 * reshapedString.append(getShape(at,pre_step)); i=i+1;
                 * continue;
                 * 
                 * 
                 * } else if (what_case_post==TASHKEEL){
                 * post_post=Temp.charAt(i+3);
                 * what_case_post_post=getCase(post_post); if
                 * ((what_case_post_post
                 * &RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK)==RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK){
                 * reshapedString.append(getShape(at,2+pre_step)); i=i+1;
                 * 
                 * continue;
                 * 
                 * } else { reshapedString.append(getShape(at,pre_step)); i=i+1;
                 * continue;
                 * 
                 * }
                 * 
                 * 
                 * 
                 * 
                 * 
                 * }
                 */else {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                }
            case RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR_LAM:
            case RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR:
                if ((what_case_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TANWEEN) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TASHKEEL) {
                    post_post = Temp.charAt(i + 3);
                    what_case_post_post = getCase(post_post);
                    if ((what_case_post_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;

                    } else {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;

                    }

                } else {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                }

            case RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                i = i + 1;
                continue;
            case TASHKEEL:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;
                pre_pre = pre;
                continue;
            case TANWEEN:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;
                pre_pre = pre;
                continue;

            default:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;

            }

        }

        return reshapedString.toString();
    }

    public static String reshape_browser(String Str) {
        String Temp = " " + Str + " ";
        char pre, at, post;
        StringBuilder reshapedString = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        int len = Str.length();
        boolean pre_can_connect = false;
        char post_post;
        char pre_pre = ' ';

        while (i < len) {
            pre = Temp.charAt(i);
            at = Temp.charAt(i + 1);
            post = Temp.charAt(i + 2);

            int which_case = getCase(at);
            int what_case_post = getCase(post);
            int what_case_pre = getCase(pre);
            int what_case_post_post;
            int what_case_pre_pre;
            // which_case=0x000F&
            // Log.v("what case"," :" +which_case);

            if (at == '\u060c') {
                reshapedString.append(',');
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            // if (at==)

            int pre_step = 0;
            if (what_case_pre == TASHKEEL) {
                pre = pre_pre;
                what_case_pre = getCase(pre);
            }
            if ((what_case_pre & LEFT_CHAR_MASK) == LEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                pre_step = 1;

            }

            switch (which_case & 0x000F) {

            case NOTUSED_CHAR:
            case NOTARABIC_CHAR:

                reshapedString.append(at);
                pre_can_connect = false;
                i++;
                continue;
            case NORIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;
                continue;
            case TATWEEL_CHAR:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                pre_can_connect = false;
                i++;
                continue;
            case RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR_LAM:

                if ((what_case_post & 0x000F) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_ALEF) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(post, pre_step + 2));
                    i = i + 2;
                    pre_can_connect = false;
                    continue;
                } else if ((what_case_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    pre_can_connect = true;
                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TANWEEN) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TASHKEEL) {
                    post_post = Temp.charAt(i + 2);
                    what_case_post_post = getCase(post_post);
                    if ((what_case_post_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;
                        pre_can_connect = true;
                        continue;

                    } else {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;

                    }

                } else {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                }

            case RIGHT_LEFT_CHAR:
                if ((what_case_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TANWEEN) {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                } else if (what_case_post == TASHKEEL) {
                    post_post = Temp.charAt(i + 3);
                    what_case_post_post = getCase(post_post);
                    if ((what_case_post_post & RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) == RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_MASK) {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 2 + pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;
                        pre_can_connect = true;
                        continue;

                    } else {
                        reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                        i = i + 1;
                        continue;

                    }

                } else {
                    reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                    i = i + 1;
                    continue;

                }
            case RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR_ALEF:
            case RIGHT_NOLEFT_CHAR:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, pre_step));
                i = i + 1;
                continue;
            case TASHKEEL:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;
                pre_pre = pre;
                continue;
            case TANWEEN:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;
                pre_pre = pre;
                continue;

            default:
                reshapedString.append(getShape(at, 0));
                i++;

            }

        }

        return reshapedString.toString();
    }

    static int getCase(char ch) {
        if (ch < 0x0621 || ch > 0x06d2) {
            return 0;

        } else {

            return allchar[(int) ch - 0x0621][1];

        }

    }

    static char getShape(char ch, int which_shape) {

        return allchar[(int) ch - 0x0621][2 + which_shape];

    }
}
```