# Arabic letters coming as special characters

Tags: android, android-view, textview

Hi i am recieving the text from server which is arabic and im encoding the input stream as below

```
String strInputStream = Utility.Service.inputStreamToString(n_oInputStream);
        try 
        {
            n_oInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(strInputStream.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but the arabic letters are coming as ?????????????????? but from the server i am getting correct arabic letters

Comment: What do you want to do with this text? You want to display it in a Textview?

Comment: I think you will need to use custom font file for arabic letters.

Comment: @ Basim sherif: yes i then use the text view to display the letters from this input stream.but then i get the ????????? as the result on the devices.
@yashdeep Patel : can i know the ttf required?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778213/android-arabic-font

Comment: Roboto font may help you.

Comment: @yashdeep patel: the problem is i already have a font which i need it in my app...if i change to this font my whole view will be adjusted to this fone right

Comment: Yes, At a time you can use only one font to any text view. You can't tow font files. Which font are you using? And are you sure you are getting Arabic letter where you get "?????".?