# Text view shows Arabic sentence in a disconnected way

Tags: android

I am trying to display a sentence in Arabic. For testing it I have used Google translator and found out the equivalent sentence in Arabic for "Hello World" which is مرحبا العالم

I have pasted it in "String.xml" and used it like this in my code:

```
txt1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sample_arabic_text));
```

But android is displaying it in text view like this (not in a connected way):

[image]

Then I tried to print the content of the text view like this:

```
System.out.println(txt1.getText());
```

Then it printed corrected in logcat.

I am bit confused why it is not getting displayed in text view correctly. Please help me to find a solution for this issue.

Comment: May be something to do with font kerning.  Did you try using different fonts in the textview?

Comment: @AleksG: I have tried to use Roboto-Regular.ttf as mentioned in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778213/android-arabic-font, but the result is same.

Comment: MAybe you should try with a different encoding in the layout, e.g.: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> I guess that's what is currently in place, try with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1256"?> and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @g00dy: Application is not even running when I change it like that. It says unknown encoding.

Comment: Sorry about that, here's what i found: `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.Encoding.html`, there are 4 possible encodings for the xml in Android: ISO_8859_1, US_ASCII , UTF_16  and UTF_8, try one of those.

Comment: @g00dy: Tried all. But same result

Comment: Ok, one last thing that I can think of: try - txt1.setText(getString(R.string.sample_arabic_text)); Otherwise I'm really out of ideas, sorry ... :-(

Comment: @g00dy: Still the same issue. In log cat it is printing correctly, but in text view it is in disconnected form. Anyways, thanx for the effort bro

Comment: I'm not putting my arms down so ealily :) Which Android you run this on? Because I found some interesting fact: Click the right click Button and change to 4.0.3 and press OK then it is Done :) 2.1 it does not support Arabic, 2.3 not Full support of Arabic , 3.x supports fully Arabic. Also put your sting in String folder inside values, not values-ar for now.

Comment: It might also be related to the default fond, which Android uses. I found somewhere, that it renders badly the Arabic characters, try changing the font to see if anything changes and localize the problem.

Comment: Third attempt :) : We'll need the font file for Arabic fonts. For example ,we have the Arabic font file name as arabicfont.ttf. Save this file into the assets folder then use the bellow code:
`arabicTextview.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"arabicfont.ttf"));
arabicTextView.setText("ur text");`
Like wise we can set any type of text with out using the Locale. Hope that at least that will work ok.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32002/discussion-between-roy-mathew-and-g00dy)

Comment: @g00dy: I have already tried the third solution of yours. But no use.
When I tried with tahoma.ttf it looks bit better. Still it is not in a connected way like in Google Translate.
I am using the 2.3 emulator and android compile version is 4.2.2

Comment: Please tell me how did you do it ?

Comment: Lol, congrats for finding the solution! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by putting two classes from this link:

https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper

and following the instructions in this link:

http://blog.amr-gawish.com/39/arabic-language-in-android/

Steps:

1.Download the zip folder from first link
2. Put the two classes named "ArabicReshaper" and "ArabicUtilities" in to the package and change the package name to our application's package name

3. After that put this code in the on create from the second link:

   AssetManager manager=this.getAssets();

   ```
   manager.open("tahoma.ttf");
   TextView tv=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.testMe);
   tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(manager, "tahoma.ttf"));
   tv.setTextSize(50f);
   tv.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape("adsdads الحمد لله asdad"));
   ```

Note: We have to download "tahoma.ttf" and put in the asset folder.