# How to set Arabic text plus English text in EditText right to Left

Tags: android, android-edittext, arabic

I am setting below text in an EditText as a hint

> مرحبا هذا هو الاختبار. Test

But it shows as below

> Test مرحبا هذا هو الاختبار.

I want to set hint as I gave string in hint.

```
      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:lines="1"
            android:hint="مرحبا هذا هو الاختبار. Test"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: Your xml and java code?

Comment: I don't know what is the reason but did u try to set programatically **Edittext.setHint("yourhint");**

Comment: @SaravanarajaT I tried it already.

Comment: Try if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17190781/1777090) works

Answer (score 3):

You can just add "‏‏‏‏\u200F" to the first of your string

var text = "‏‏‏‏\u200F" + "Test" + "آقرین"  = Test آقرین

Answer (score 1):

**all you need just add**

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple language in same direction as arabic is rtl and english is ltr, so when you right arabic at start it jumps to the end of string and it finds english text so it goes to start f english text and therefore it prints english text and than arabic on UI.

So for your exact need you need to use two different edittexts for arabic and english and you can put them on same UI closely so it will look like both are written in same edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be at the beginning in this scenario? Since the beginning is the end in Arabic.
Also, you wouldn't use a full stop at the beginning (end) of an Arabic sentence.

Answer (score -3):

Set your hint text from:

```
android:hint="@string/yourhintText"
```

Comment: This was not what was asked for. Please check the questions before giving answer. @dharam