# Diacritic rendering incorrectly

Tags: android, fonts, xamarin.android, rendering, diacritics

I have been working with Arabic in my application and using QuranSaleem font, it shows correctly in web and IOS applications like this

[image: correct word]

but it is being rendered incorrectly like this

[image: wrong word]

I have changed fonts but to no avail, there is always some problem with rendering in android. what is the solution to this problem?

```
     Typefaces.SetFontQuranSaleem(holder.VerseArTextView);
```

and here is the code for this method

```
     class Typefaces
 {
    Context context;
    static Typeface quranFontSaleem;
    public Typefaces(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        quranFontSaleem = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "Fonts/QuranFontSaleem.ttf");

    }
    public static void SetFontQuranSaleem(TextView textview)
    {
        textview.SetTypeface(quranFontSaleem, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
    }
 }
```

Comment: No idea: [without showing the code you're using to draw this text](/help/how-to-ask), it's virtually impossible to tell what you might be forgetting.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have added the code now. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "it shows correctly in web and IOS applications"? Android also has webviews, does it look correct "on a web page, viewed in a current version browser on a modern version of Android" or does it break in any and all contexts on Android? (native as well as web)

Comment: Its build on xamarin. It only breaks in android application only, this font is also used in web application as well as IOS application and the correct font image is from the IOS app and it also display correct font on all browsers.

Comment: "all browsers" is not enough information: you are looking at a font shaping problem on Android, so the fact that it works on other platforms does not need repeating: does it render correctly on Android when you user it in the, and incorrectly as native app? (Because Android does not use a different shaping engine, so that is the exact test you need to tell whether you're this might be bug in the shaping engine, or whether this is something specific to your native app config/code).

Comment: Yes it only renders incorrectly as in native app

Comment: what happens when you use Roboto (the proper version, with arabic support)? I did find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778213/android-arabic-font so that might be one thing to try as well.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried Roboto-Regular as mentiond in the answer in your provided link but then some characters are replaced by chinese charaters.

Comment: That's fine, we're trying roboto to see if the problem you're seeing with the QuranSaleem font also manifests in other fonts that support arabic or not. Does the same diacritic repositioning happen?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your help, I finally was able to find the culprit it was the text it self which was rendering incorrectly, I changed the text and it is now rendering fine.

Comment: Good to hear you solved it, but it sounds like this wasn't actually a programming problem, but a typo in the input, in which case that's one of the established closing policies. If you agree with the conclusion that this was just input typos, then it's a good idea to just delete the question.

Comment: This was not the typo but the script was different,this same word was displaying correctly on all browsers and also in IOS native app.

Comment: In that case you answer is _not_ an answer to the original problem, and is a bad answer. "I changed the word and now it looks fine" does not solve the problem of what people should do when they need that original input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to find the culprit it was the text it self which was rendering incorrectly in the android app, I changed the text and it is now rendering fine.

I replaced "شَیْـًٔـا" with "شَيْئًا" and it was rendering fine.